# Writing adaptive PHP methods?

Tags: php, class, design-patterns, methods

Let's say I have a class called Books. Inside that class I have a method that fetches the title, price and category of a single book or several books. So something like this:

```
public function fetchRows () {
  $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT Title, Price, Category FROM Books");
  $sql->execute();
  return $sql->fetchAll();
}
```

All fine and good, but lets say I now want to fetch another row, `order` the result and `limit` the amount of rows returned. Writing another method just for that would work, but then that would result in a ridiculous amount of methods and that is just messy and doesn't adhere to the DRY rule. I could use arguments to customize the prepare statement then I would prbably end up writing the entire query inside an argument and that as well doesn't seem to be solid and clean.

My question is how can I write/structure methods/classes that adapt to what the end user is trying to get?

Sorry that this really isn't a question to a specific problem. I have read some material about my problem, but I have difficulty wrapping that pattern around my head and I am hoping somebody could offer an explanation or example that might help me understand this.

Comment: Yes, quite often you will have a separate abstration to handle database interactions. So another class entirely, you can then pass all your parameters to this and process all db requests with a simple API-like interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using an ORM (Object Relational Mapper) that sits on top of your database?  I highly recommend Doctrine 2 http://www.doctrine-project.org .  This way, you can treat rows in your database table as objects: All of the database interaction is abstracted away (you can still run SQL queries directly if you need to).

In case you're not familiar with the concepts of ORMs, Doctrine enables you to write code like the following:

```
$user = new User();
$user->username = 'test';
$user->email = 'test@example.com';
$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManager->flush();
```

You've just run `INSERT INTO user (username, email) VALUES ('test', 'test@example.com');` without writing any SQL.

Similarly, users could be retrieved as follows:

`$user = $entityManager->getRepository('User')->findOneByUsername('test')`

`$user = $entityManager->getRepository('User')->findOneByEmail('test@example.com')`

These finder methods are generated automatically for you, based on the fields present on the user table, helping you to keep the code DRY.

Comment: Downvoter: Care to explain why?  I feel this answers the question.

Comment: I did not dv you but I think the issue is that you are suggesting to add finder methods, while the OP is concerned about adding them (cf "that would result in a ridiculous amount of methods"). What would probably help the OP would be to show how to use DQL and Criteria objects assembled from user input.

Comment: The finder methods are generated automatically by Doctrine: They do not need to be written by the user.

Comment: Not everyone knows that though so you might want to add it.

Answer (score -1):

> adapt to what the end user is trying to get?

You are entering shaky grounds here. What you might want to allow the end user is to give her access to the database layer so she can prepare queries.

Otherwise you start to re-invent the wheel. And I doubt you really have that many functions with that many parameters to be honest.

So this highly depends on your end-user. If the end-user want's to do much, provide the software in the source-form so the end-user can modify the software as needed.

Until then, release your software and get feedback from the end-user which functionality is needed for real.

That saying for your application an ORM might just be a useless overhead but instead you just want some little more functionality on top of PDO like lazy queries and some functionality to rename column names later on.

```
$result = PDOQuery::create('* FROM config')->limit(2);

$result->orderBy('`option`');

$result->aliasNames(['option' => 'name'], $removeOther = true);    

foreach ($result as $row) {
    print_r($row);
}
```

This is just exemplary, the code would just provide the rows as assoc arrays:

```
Array
(
    [name] => Insert Option 50e60ca17bdf4
)
Array
(
    [name] => Insert Option A 50e78a79ead49
)
```

Only executed when it comes to the foreach (e.g. you can pass that into the view and if the view does not need it, the database query is never executed).

You can further and further extend it, e.g. everything that defines the query will become a query definition you can pass around.

You could make the iterator a stacked iterator so that if the query has been executed you could apply a limit on the result instead of running the query again. And what not.

All this actually does is enhacing the interface of PDO according to the needs you would have, so you need to write that component on your own.

It should be also more decoupled than outlined as in the example code above.